# Use mixin method over inherited one

Tags: ruby, inheritance, mixins

Say I create the following class:

```
class Node < Struct.new(:data, :left, :right)
  def each(&block)
    ...
  end
end
```

As you know, `select` is defined by both `Struct` and `Enumerable` (the latter being included in `Struct`).

How can I do `Node.new.select` and trigger `Enumerable`'s implementation rather than `Struct`'s one? The reason I need this is that I have implemented a custom `each` for my class and I would like `select` to use it (hence I need `Enumerable#select`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can modify the source code of `Node`, then let it `prepend Enumerable` instead of `include Enumerable`.

If you can't, then you can grab the instance method `select` from `Enumerable` and `bind` it to the instance of `Node`, then `call` it.

```
node = Node.new(...)
Enumerable.instance_method(:select).bind(node).call
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
class Node < Struct.new(:data, :left, :right)
  #... 
  define_method(:select, Enumerable.instance_method(:select)) 
end
```

Shameless plug: this is the topic of [RubyTapas #466, "Ancestral Behavior"](https://www.rubytapas.com/2017/02/13/episode-466-ancestral-behavior/)

Comment: Looks nice, but I prefer @Aetherus's solution more. Even though it potentially hides other common methods from `Struct` besides `select`.

Comment: @aetherus solution doesn't hide anything.

Comment: Well, the second solution doesn't. I see what you mean about the first solution.